# Foreign keys in SQL while using arrays

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, psql

I have a table 'person' having a attribute ID (primary key).  I want to store an array of person IDs in another table. How to define the foreign key in that table referring to table 'person'?

Comment: Do you mean that the type of the attribute in the other table is an array, or that it is the same type as attribute ID in person?

Answer (score 1):

In the creation or alteration of your table include: `Foreign_key_name int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(ID)`, assuming that `Person.ID` is of type `int`.

The exact command syntax might differ depending on your database type.

A good guide giving examples for MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: OP asked for an ARRAY of person IDs. This answer shows how to create a column to store single foreign IDs.